# I need output values without array brackets in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used checklist-model plugin for my project. It works well. But i need the output values without array brackets. For example if i chose 20 c checkbox in my code, it appeared with ["20 c"]. But here i need the output "20 c".

My html Code

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1" >
<label ng-repeat="temp in temps">
  <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="tempValue.temps" checklist-value="temp"> {{temp}}
</label><br />
<input type="text" value="{{tempValue.temps}}"  />
</div>
```

My Controller Code

```
app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope) {
  $scope.temps = [
    '18 C ', 
    '19 C ', 
    '20 C ', 
    '21 C ',
    '22 C ', 
    '23 C ', 
    '24 C ', 
    '25 C ',
    '26 C ', 
    '27 C ', 
    '28 C ', 
    '29 C ',
    '30 C '
  ];
  $scope.tempValue = {
    temps: ['20 C ' , '24 C ' ]
  };

});
```

Comment: What about in the case where multiple checkboxes are selected? Do you want to write out "20 C " , "24 C " (comma delimited list)?

Comment: <input type="text" value="{{ tempValue.temps[0] }}"  />  ??

Comment: I want my output without brackets & double quotes. Just like 20 c, 24c

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to show the first item the the `$scope.tempValue` array you can do this:

```
{{ tempValue.temps[0] }}
```

If you want all the values listed, split by some delimiter - in this example, a comma - you can do this:

```
{{ tempValue.temps.join(', ') }}
```

Comment: @BhavanKumarNatarajan if it works than you'd consider accepting this answer.